# mongoose findById or findone is not wotking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to query courses in my collection and list them but am failing to update them

I have tried using the findone method as well as findById

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises', {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log(' Successfuly connected to mongodb...'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Ooops! something went wrong', err));

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [ String ],
    author: String,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const Course = mong.model('Course', courseSchema);
```

```
  async function updateCourse(id) {
    const course = await Course.findById(id);

    if (!course) return;

    course.isPublished = false;
    course.author = 'Kalisha';

    // course.set({
    //     isPublished: true,
    //     author: 'Kalisha Malama'
    // });

      const  result = await course.save();
      console.log(result);
  }
```

```
updateCourse('5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb');
```

Am not getting any error...my console just shows successfully connected to mongodb...

Comment: Well `if (!course) return;` is of course not going to be an error and would explain why no logging happens from any of the rest of the code. The very first thing to check is that the `id` you are sending in the request actually exists.

Comment: I suggest showing how you verify that you think a document actually exists. My money says you are expecting to find a document in a collection called `course` when mongoose is actually looking for a collection called `courses`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `findOneAndUpdate`

```
await Course.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},{$set:{isPublished:false,author:"Kalisha"}}).exec()
```

Remember to use `.exec()` and if you want updated document to be returned use `{new:true}`

Comment: Not true. You don't need the `exec()` since you can `Course.findById(id).then(result => ...)` without a problem. All of my code ( and there's a lot of it ) never calls the exec. I just `await`. If you actually check the mongoose documentation, the returned object is a `Query`, which of course has a [`then()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-then) and that is all you need to meet the API spec for a `Promise` in this case. `findOneAndUpdate()` is better than doing `find .. change ..save`, however my money is on a different cause of the problem.

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` returns a promise.Here I used `await` not `.then`.

Comment: Why would you think there is a difference? I'm pointing out that `exec()` makes no difference. Pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`findById` returns a query and not a promise.
For it to execute the query and return a promise use:

`await Course.findById(id).exec();`

[Mongoose findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

Comment: Not true. You don't need the `exec()` since you can `Course.findById(id).then(result => ...)` without a problem. All of my code ( and there's a lot of it ) never calls the exec. I just `await`. If you actually check the mongoose documentation, the returned object is a `Query`, which of course has a [`then()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-then) and that is all you need to meet the API spec for a `Promise` in this case.

Comment: Not quite.  [Mongoose queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me try this and your course will be updated

```
   async function updateCourse(id) {
        await Course.find({
    _id: id
    })
    .then(doc => {
    doc.isPublished = false;
    doc.author = 'Kalisha';
    doc.save();
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I imported the database and I think thats why it was not working but after creating  a new database the code works fine....thanks a lot to all those that made an effort to help...